# PHP5 - Error when calling class property as function

Tags: php, function, oop, php-5.6

```
$f = function($v) {
    return $v + 1;
}

echo $f(4);
// output -> 5
```

The above works perfectly fine. However, I cannot reproduce this correctly when `f` is a property of a class.

```
class MyClass {
    public $f;

    public function __construct($f) {
        $this->f = $f;
    }

    public function methodA($a) {
        echo $this->f($a);
    }
}

// When I try to call the property `f`, PHP gets confused
// and thinks I am trying to call a method of the class ...
$myObject = new myClass($f);
$myObject->methodA(4);
```

The above will result in an error:

```
Call to undefined method MyClass::f()
```

Comment: what does the first `$f` equal?

Comment: `myClass($f);`-> where `$f` is defined?

Comment: @AlivetoDie `f` is not a method, it is a function stored in a variable passed to the constructor as a class property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that it is trying to make sense of

```
echo $this->f($a);
```

And as you've found it wants to call a member function `f` in the class.  If you change it to

```
echo ($this->f)($a);
```

It interprets it as you want it to.

PHP 5.6
Thanks to ADyson for the comment, think this works

```
$f = $this->f;
echo $f($a);
```

Comment: https://eval.in/997679

Comment: maybe worth noting this only works in PHP7

Comment: I thought that would work, but it results in a syntax error `unexpected '('`

Comment: @AlivetoDie the assumption is that the input is a function... e.g. https://eval.in/997678

Comment: @TT4M.C see my comment - are you using PHP 5? https://eval.in/997680 shows it fails in PHP 5, but https://eval.in/997678 shows it works in PHP 7

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I am using PHP 5.6

Comment: @TT4M.C in that case you cannot use this syntax unfortunately.

Comment: `$f = $this->f; echo $f($a);` in PHP5 you can assign the property to a variable first ... then it works

Comment: @NigelRen sorry just seen your update, in the meantime I had posted an answer along the same lines. Although it seems the nominated dupe covers both cases already.

Answer (score 2):

While Nigel Ren's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50117174/5947043) will work in PHP 7, this slightly expanded syntax will work in PHP 5 as well:

```
class MyClass {
    public $f;

    public function __construct($f) {
        $this->f = $f;
    }

    public function methodA($a) {
      $func = $this->f;
      echo $func($a);
    }
}

$f = function($v) {
    return $v + 1;
};

$myObject = new myClass($f);
$myObject->methodA(4);
```

See https://eval.in/997686 for a working demo.